# Javascript JSON.Parse error if string with escaped backslashes followed by capital letter

Tags: javascript, json

Pretty simple question really.  Why can I parse `'FOO\\bAR'` but not `'FOO\\BAR'`?

```
let sample = [
  '{"a": "FOO\BAR"}',
  '{"b": "FOO\\bAR"}',
  '{"c": "FOO\\\\BAR"}',
  '{"d": "FOO\\BAR"}'
];

for(const item of sample) {
  console.log(item);
  console.log(JSON.parse(item));
}
```

Result:

```
{"a": "FOOBAR"}
{ a: 'FOOBAR' }
{"b": "FOO\bAR"}
{ b: 'FOO\bAR' }
{"c": "FOO\\BAR"}
{ c: 'FOO\\BAR' }
{"d": "FOO\BAR"}
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token B in JSON at position 11
```

Comment: I get _“bad escaped character”_ in Firefox, which explains it. [`\b` is a valid escape sequence](//developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#escape_notation), `\B` is not. Related: [jquery 1.9.1 fails to parse JSON that contains escaped backslash](/q/25669978/4642212).

Answer (score 0):

Lookup JSON special characters and escaping them, \b is a special character.

Comment: No, it isn't.  Try ```JSON.parse('{"d": "FOO \b BAR"}')```